# Какую версию Python выбрать?

Tags: python

Собираюсь изучать Python. Область применения самая обширная: Web, Machine Learning, обработка больших данных, графиков...

Какую версию выбрать? Нормально ли работает Джанго с 3 версией Python?
Для 2-й версии больше описание и самоучителей.

Comment: Как по мне, начните с 2.х и учите активно, 3.х - смотрите, сравнивайте, понимайте отличия. Я думаю, через 3-5 лет ветка 2.х догонит современную 3.х. А 3.х тем временем превратиться в 4.х или даже 5.х. Я отношусь к 3 версии как к некой стабильной бете языка, а 2 - как стабильной для промышенного кода.

Но никто не мешает писать код так, чтобы он работал в обеих версиях питона.

Comment: Принципиальная разница в производительности есть ?

Comment: @xmaster83, 

1. Принципиальной разницы нет.
2. Это вообще последнее, о чем нужно думать, - производительность конечного приложения будет в значительно большей степени зависеть от выбранных алгоритмов и архитектуры, чем языка.

Comment: Я решаю разные алгоритмические задачи с числодробилками. 2.7 обычно в 1.5 - 2 раза быстрее 3.3. (при почти одном и том же коде).

Кстати, самый большой затык - это range-xrange в циклах. В втором питоне range генерит полный список и потом итерируется. Если диапазон большой - памяти кушает много. xrange - это ленивая операция, она не отдаст следующий элемент, пока это не нужно и ей побоку на размеры диапазона. Так вот в 3 питоне range ведет себя как xrange второго, а вот xrange в третьем нет.

Comment: @KoVadim, а где затык? Все, кто более-менее программируют на питоне, знают, что xrange надо использовать почти везде. Вот если бы в 3-м питоне был xrange, и он вел бы себя как range во 2-м, это бы был затык =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учить можно обе. По сути, это один язык. А под конкретные проекты уже выбирать, что более подходящее - 2.7 или 3.

Фундаментальна разница между версиями по строгости подхода к смешиванию Юникода и байтовых строк. Стандартные типы более широко используют итераторы по умолчанию. В 3-й версии также убраны некоторые шероховатости, такие как неявные относительные импорты, синтаксис для исключений поправлен, утечка имён в списках включения (list comprehension) и т.д. Добавлен новый синтакс, например, `yield from`, который позволяет удобно программировать c такими вещами, как asyncio. Часть стандартных модулей были реорганизованы, например, `urllib2.urlopen()` функция - это `urllib.request.urlopen()` в Питоне 3. Гугл всегда подскажет, где что лежит. Поверхностные вещи, такие как print функция в 3-й версии и print инструкция во 2-м, по мере использования узнаются.

Многие проекты используют один исходный код для Питона 2 и 3. Так что даже не нужно разные API учить. [Многие популярные библиотеки могут работать на Питон 3](https://python3wos.appspot.com/).